# IE 11 и респонсивные изображения в Bootstrap 3.3.2

Tags: bootstrap, internet-explorer, responsive

Есть [сайт](http://pechdecor.ru/), построен на Bootstrap 3.3.2.
Логотип сайта и логотипы внизу страницы неправильных размеров (очень большие).
Подскажите куда смотреть, как исправить?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Вроде прописано.

Comment: а в чем проблема использовать сетку бутстрапа?...насколько я вижу, на сайте исходные размеры. И собственно ен свовсем понятно в чем проблема ваша? Вы не можете изменить размер картинок ?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц А где она не использована? Если вы знаете что то конкретное, в чем проблема не говорить загадками?

Comment: `*col-3` установлен...т е поведение ожидаемо. Если сетка такая нужна, то просто внутри поменяйте размер самой картинке...например на теге `img` поставить `width 50%` ну или какое вам там подходит...

Comment: ну [вот](http://prntscr.com/qn2lkl) я применил `width 30%` для первых 4х элементов. Вам так нужно?

Comment: и вы в вопросе пишете `IE 11`, а в теге указываете `content="IE=edge"`. Почему не `content="IE=11"`.

Comment: Для меня не понятно почему *col-3 не верно? Почему в других браузерах это отображается нормально? И зачем использовать напрямую указание размера если у нас есть botstrap?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Надо кое что прояснить, я не верстал этот шаблон, он куплен. Я не прописывал ничего в том числе и content="IE=edge", и нужна совместимость с IE9-11

Comment: если честно - не понимаю такого поведения, скажу факты, которые я нашел...`div sppb-col-sm-3` => `<a>` (хром уменьшает `<a>`, хотя этого нигде не указано, а IE берет 100%).